# JavaScript - Why different output from if/else statement while using a variable declared before the statement?

Tags: javascript

My question is about the following code:

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = ["su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa"];
var deliver = weekday[d.getDay()];

if(condition){
    if(d.getDay() == 1){
       d.setHours(d.getHours() + 24); // adds a day
    }
    if(d.getUTCMonth() == 0 && d.getUTCDate() == 1){
        // do something
    } else {
        // version 1 or version 2
    }
}

//version 1: var deliver = weekday[d.getDay()];
//           document.getElementById("leverdatum").innerHTML = deliver;

//version 2: document.getElementById("leverdatum").innerHTML = deliver;;
```

Why, if I use version 1, the output is "tu" and if I use version 2 the output is "mo"?

Comment: Because of this? `d.setHours(d.getHours() + 24); // adds a day`. You shouldn't put `var` inside block-statements becuase of variable hosting, that might take away some of the confusion.

Comment: [Version 1](http://jsbin.com/sayewa/1/edit?js,console) & [Version 2](http://jsbin.com/sayewa/2/edit?js,console) — Removing that `var` makes no difference.

Comment: I think there's more to this than you're showing - how are you seeing this output?  The additional `var` there won't make any difference, it's in the same scope.

Comment: If `condition` is `false` it doesn't do the `+24h`. I think that's what OP means.

Comment: @Quentin replace the line from version 2 with only `deliver;`

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand. What did you expect `deliver;` to do?

Comment: @Juhana `weekday[d.getDay()];` like declared on line 3

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not how JavaScript works. You can't re-initialize a variable like that, and I don't know why you would expect it to do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence (or lack thereof) of `var` on that line does absolutely nothing.

The significant part is `= weekday[d.getDay()];`.

Because it is (at the time of writing) Monday, `d.setHours(d.getHours() + 24); // adds a day` will add a day. Making the day Tuesday.

But if you don't convert the value of `d` into a day and assign it to `deliver` **after** you change the value of `d`, then you will continue to have the original string.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question!